# Как исправить ошибку в запросе?

Tags: mysql

На удаленном сервере вылетает ошибка: **Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active**. На локальном сервере ошибки нет. Использую Laravel.
Сам запрос:

```
SELECT parent.*, (main.level - parent.level + 1) as lvl, u.name
FROM books main
LEFT JOIN books parent 
ON parent.lft < main.lft 
AND parent.rgt > main.rgt 
AND parent.level = main.level - $line
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = parent.user_id
WHERE main.id = :id
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну ты используешь буферизацию на стороне MySQL. Обычно ты либо говоришь серверу - сохрани результат у себя, а я буду его "кусками" у тебя забирать. Либо же ты можешь выкачать сразу весь результирующий набор в память своим PHP.
Ты используешь первый вариант - мускуль буфер у себя в памяти держит и ты пытаешься параллельно выполнить еще какой то запрос. Тебе в сторону клиентской библиотеки (PDO полагаю) и курить за буферизацию.

Comment: Почему на локальном компьютере не вылетает ошибка?

Comment: Очевидно потому что на локальном сервере у тебя нету попытки сделать новый запрос при условии, что есть незавершенные буферизованные на стороне MySQL.

Comment: Ошибка исчезла, после того, как убрал атрибут unsigned у поля level